# GPS connection delay android

Tags: android, gps, location, delay

So I'm basically sitting with an app project, that has to scan data and give the location of let's say west coast of US while I'm sitting on the east coast.

The main problem here is that when I start the app it asks for permission to turn on "Location/GPS". If this is done and I start the scan too quickly it'll get my location for 0.0LAT and 0.0LONG which will give me an insane distance between me and the other location and is stuck in an endless while loop (probably a rookie thing that I have no clue how to exit, see the while loop futher down).

- I belive I've searched almost everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution, my best answer is to make a sleep thread timer for it, and make it try to get correct location after 20sec?
- Another thing I could think of is using onStatusChange although I'm not entirely sure.

Any ideas out there?

```
while(mLat.equals("0.0") && mLon.equals("0.0")) {

            mLat = String.valueOf(gpsHelper.getLatitude());
            mLon = String.valueOf(gpsHelper.getLongitude());

            Location.distanceBetween(Double.valueOf(mLat), 
            Double.valueOf(mLon), Double.valueOf(lat), Double.valueOf(lon), dist);
            System.out.println("lat: " + lat + "\nlong: " + lon + "\nmLat: " + mLat + "\nmLong: " + mLon + "\n" + "\nDist: " + Arrays.toString(dist));
        }
```

So here is the GPSHelper:

```
public final class GPSHelper implements LocationListener {

//**************************************************************************/
// VARIABLES
//**************************************************************************/
//region Variables

private String TAG = "GPSHelper";

// Context using GPS
private final Context mContext;

// Flag for GPS status
private boolean canGetLocation = false;

// Properties
private Location location;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private double speed;

// The minimum Distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 1 meter
// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1; // 1 millisecond

// Declaring a Location Manager
private LocationManager locationManager;

//endregion

//**************************************************************************/
// PROPERTIES
/***************************************************************************/
//region Properties

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

private void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}

//endregion

//**************************************************************************/
// CONSTRUCTOR
/***************************************************************************/
//region Constructor

public GPSHelper(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    connectToGPS();
}

//endregion

//**************************************************************************/
// FUNCTIONS
//**************************************************************************/
//region Functions

//***************************************************/
// Connect til GPS
//***************************************************/
public void connectToGPS() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Flag for GPS turned on
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.i(TAG, "Enabled: " + isGPSEnabled);

        // Is GPS turned on
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

            updateLocation();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = false;
            this.setLocation(null);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

//***************************************************/
// Update location
//***************************************************/
private void updateLocation() throws SecurityException {
    // Get location
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (getLocation() != null) {
            latitude = getLocation().getLatitude();
            longitude = getLocation().getLongitude();
            speed = getLocation().getSpeed();
        }
    }
}

//***************************************************/
// Stop use of GPS
//***************************************************/
public void disconnectFromGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSHelper.this);
    }
}

//***************************************************/
// Get latitude/Breddegrad
//***************************************************/
public double getLatitude() {
    updateLocation();

    if (getLocation() != null) {
        return latitude;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

//***************************************************/
// Get longitude/Længdegrad
//***************************************************/
public double getLongitude() {
    updateLocation();

    if (getLocation() != null) {
        return longitude;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

//***************************************************/
// Get speed
//***************************************************/
public double getSpeed() {
    updateLocation();

    if (getLocation() != null) {
        double tempSpeed = speed / 3.6;
        //DecimalFormat  df = new DecimalFormat("#");
        //tempSpeed = Double.valueOf(df.format(tempSpeed));
        //tempSpeed = Math.round(tempSpeed);
        return tempSpeed;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

//***************************************************/
// Check for connection to satellites
//***************************************************/
public boolean canGetLocation() {

    return this.canGetLocation;

}

//***************************************************/
// Ask user to turn on GPS
//***************************************************/
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Set title
    alertDialog.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.gps_helper_gps_status));
    // Set message
    alertDialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.gps_helper_gps_is_not_enabled));

    // "Ja" button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(mContext.getString(R.string.yes),
            (dialog, which) -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            });

    // "Nej" button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(mContext.getString(R.string.no),
            (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());

    // Show message
    alertDialog.show();
}

//endregion

//**************************************************************************/
// EVENTS
//**************************************************************************/
//region Events

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.setLocation(location);

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    speed = location.getSpeed();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
//endregion}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code when you are retrieving GPS data ?

Comment: @Maxouille yes sry, just updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't `updateLocation()` after requesting Location updates :

```
 if (isGPSEnabled) {
        this.canGetLocation = true;
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

    updateLocation();
}
```

Here, `updateLocation()` is called before any `onLocationChanged()` is called. I think that's why your values are "0". You should call `updateLocation()` inside the `onLocationChanged()`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work, it's still stuck in the while loop with same "myLocation" "0.0;0.0". Any other suggestions? :(

Comment: Did you request the permission to use GPS correctly ?

Comment: I believe it is. Cause as mentioned, if I wait somewhere between 5-20sec it'll get the connection to GPS and I'll be able to get out of the while loop, since it gets my position.